# Calculation of dimensions for a 3D bounding Box

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, bounding-box, point-clouds

EDIT: I am trying to calculate the dimensions of 3D bounding boxes using three vectors that contain elements representing the 3 coordinates of my box, namely Cluster_x, Cluster_y, and Cluster_z. The algorithm I am applying to find the values for the center is as below. I don't know where am I going wrong.

```
            tFloat32 x_max = *std::max_element(Cluster_x.begin(), Cluster_x.end());
            tFloat32 x_min = *std::min_element(Cluster_x.begin(), Cluster_x.end());

            tFloat32 y_max = *std::max_element(Cluster_y.begin(), Cluster_y.end());
            tFloat32 y_min = *std::min_element(Cluster_y.begin(), Cluster_y.end());

            tFloat32 z_max = *std::max_element(Cluster_z.begin(), Cluster_z.end());
            tFloat32 z_min = *std::min_element(Cluster_z.begin(), Cluster_z.end());


                //Center//

            tFloat32 c_x = (x_max - x_min) / 2;
            tFloat32 c_y = (y_max - y_min) / 2;
            tFloat32 c_z = (z_max - z_min) / 2;

            cetuc::BoundingBox NewBox(cetuc::Point3D(c_x,c_y,c_z), cetuc::Point3D(8, 8, 10), cetuc::Point3D(0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: If you are using 3 vectors to describe a box I can only presume one of them already is it's center.

Comment: Are you working in C or C++?  Make your mind up!  Are the objects at the end of the vectors equally heavy?  That will affect the centroid calculation. You're going to need to find out what the rotation means.

Comment: If it's only three vectors to describe the box, one of the vectors has to be a diagonal and the midpoint of that vector would be the centre.

Comment: The three vectors are containing the dimensions of all the points in a point cloud cluster representing an object. so the three vectors have all the x, y, and z values of all the points in separate vectors. I am working on C++ but I added C since it can cover more people. I am stumped at the basic logic behind calculating the dimensions of the box.  

My professor is okay with 0 rotation as well. But the extent is where I am lost.

Comment: @Brandon the x,y and z coordinates of the center of the box is being calculated by finding the center of the respective vectors indeed. But, for finding the extent, do I simply find the length of the edge using max and minimum elements of the vectors or should I be calculating the distance from the center to the corners or from center to the center of the faces of the box. that is my primary confusion.

Comment: Do you use AABB? Cos `extent = max - center` is correct for AA box only.

Comment: I am trying for the AA  one. But I will settle for an independent box as well at this point.

Comment: AA box is much simpler to do. `center_x = (x_max - x_min) /2` is not correct. Actually, it is extent expression :-) Correct is `center_x = (x_max + x_min) /2`

Comment: thanks a lot michael! Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

To make `std::max_element` work you must provide either `operator<` overloading for your element type `tFloat32` or predicate for comparison. And in your case, it is better to use [std::minmax_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)

Comment: I have been trying for it as well. I hope to solve it with minimax. I need the min and max basically to calculate the center and extent of the enclosing bounding box. Any idea what formula should I use for the extent? I believe I have figured out the center with (max-min)/2 for x,y and z.

Comment: Does the minmax_element return value of the said element or just the position? the link you mentioned in the comment has only one example that mentions the position.

Comment: @DamienArt1234 It returns a pair of iterators. You can find both position and value from them.

Comment: I tried using the minimax and I got errors saying that it requires 3 arguments and only 2 are being provided. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: my current algorithm to create bounding boxes and separating the clusters is like this. Please tell me where am I making the mistake here. I believe its either looping the w
rong way or calculating the min and max: